# How to uninstall python in ubuntu completely and reinstalling it?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

The default python version was 2.7.12 in ubuntu.
***I installed python2.7.13 using the below commands.***

Then download using the following command:

```
version=2.7.13
cd ~/Downloads/
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$version/Python-$version.tgz
```

Extract and go to the directory:

```
tar -xvf Python-$version.tgz
cd Python-$version
```

Now, install using the command you just tried, using checkinstall instead to make it easier to uninstall if needed:

```
./configure
sudo make install
```

Now there is some issue in pandas(giving no module named pandas when I try to import but if we try to install it shows required already satisfied) so I want to completely remove python 2.7.13 and reinstall python 2.7.12. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't try to uninstall default python otherwise chances are many of your components of your ubuntu stop working. Just use virtual environments if you want to use different pythons.

Comment: Why do you install 2.7.13 and not the latest 2.7.14?

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint/

Comment: There is some problem in pandas package in python 2.7.14 on ubuntu

Answer (score 12):

My python was corrupted due to some module. So I planned to re-installed or remove the python completely from my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.  But `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7`  command was also failing and was throwing same error.  So I finally Did few hacks and cracks. Here are the steps -

Removing all python version manually

```
 - sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python2.x as well as python3.x
 - sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.x as well as python3.x
 - sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.x as well as python 3.x
```

Updating Ubuntu

```
 - sudo apt-get update
```

In Between if you get this error **The package  needs to be reinstalled ubuntu** Then  Run following command

```
sudo vi /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And delete all the lines from above file for the package which was expecting re-install and run `sudo apt-get update` again.

Now download a python tgz file from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and unzip it and CD into it

```
./configure
make test
sudo make install
```

Python should be installed now.  Check by running python

Comment: What is the result of 'which python' and 'python --version' after install?
You deleted python from /usr/bin but after re-install it would be in /usr/local/bin/. I don't think these are same.