# Failed to create virtual environment pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I need to create new virtual environment in PyCharm. There are already some files in the folder.

This is how my project looks like:

[image]

I want to create venv in `heureka-negativni-reviews`

I try: File -> New project.

I switch this settings:

[image]

to have Python 3.10 as an interpreter and to create venv in `heureka-negativni-reviews`

[image]

But when I click on create, I got:

[image]

EDIT:

I found that I am not able to select Python 3.10 as an interpreter:

[image]

But I cannot click `OK` when I select Python 3.10:

[image]

What is the problem, please?

Comment: Does it work if you try python3.8?

Comment: Also does the folder of your project already contain a .idea folder?

Comment: @Tobi208 No, it does not contain .idea. Yes, it works when I try python 3.8. But I need Python 3.10

Comment: Are you sure your path to python3.10 is correct and if the installation location is valid? ```usr/bin/python3.8``` seems to work but not ```bin/python3.10```. Does ```bin/python3.10``` possibly require root/admin privileges to create a venv?

Comment: @Tobi208 it might be a problem. See my edit, please

Comment: on a command line try
`$ python3 --version`
if it shows version 3.10.x then try
`$ python3 -m venv </path/to/new/virtual/environment>`
then tell about your results

Comment: @woodz python3 --version gives me 3.8, python --version gives me 3.10...

Comment: That explains your problem. On a cmd line have you tried `$ python -m venv </path/to/new/virtual/environment>`, will it do? It should create a venv within python 3.10. Can you also post the results of `$ pip --version` and `$ pip3 --version`?

Comment: @woodz When I try `python -m venv venv/` I got `Error: Command '['/home/vojta/Desktop/INTERNET_HANDEL/HEUREKA/heureka-negativni-reviews/venv/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.` Both pip --version and  pip3 --version gives `pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: Now we see the reason, why your IDE is not able to create your venv, since the command line isn't either, which is the set of commands your IDE typically uses.
Also your python setup seems to be messed. `/home/vojta/Desktop/INTERNET_HANDEL/HEUREKA/heureka-negativni-reviews/venv/bin/python` seems not to be a general system path. It looks that you build your own version of python and installed it by a specific prefix.
Installing python correctly is off the topic here

Comment: would it suit your needs to create a new environment using conda and not with pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we see the reason, why your IDE is not able to create your venv, since the command line isn't either, which is the set of commands your IDE typically uses.

The pip and pip3 belongs to python3.8 and that is another problem, if you want to install python packages for python 3.10, which isn't possible this time without system invention.

Also your python setup seems to be messed.

```
/home/vojta/Desktop/INTERNET_HANDEL/HEUREKA/heureka-negativni-reviews/venv/bin/python
```

seems not to be a general system path. It looks that you built your own version of python and installed it by a specific prefix. Installing python correctly is off the topic here.

There are [different installers for different platforms](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3102/) which provide install instruction inside their archives.

Before doing this, it's recommended to clean up your messed installation first.
You may find information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844746/how-to-uninstall-all-python-versions-and-use-the-default-system-version-of-os-x) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48899604/how-to-uninstall-python-in-ubuntu-completely-and-reinstalling-it).

It could also be, that you are trying to create another venv from within an already sourced venv. Such kind of composed venvs can lead to confusion and that would explain your path above a bit more, which contains `/venv/`.

Also manually remove all your custom python versions from your `/home/vojta/` directory, like `$ rm -r /home/vojta/Desktop/INTERNET_HANDEL`

Answer (score -1):

First ensure that the Python interpreter is added to the list available (by adding as an 'Existing environment').

Then add a venv via [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env)

Then drag and drop your existing files to the venv directory.
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxXlI.png) [with venv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgrkP.png) [after drag and drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqOEp.png)

Comment: For `Existing environment` I see only <No interpreter>. The problem is that I cannot even create venv in Python 3.10.

Comment: I suggest you try installing the latest 3.10.2. Then run the test module:    `./python -m test`