# How do I uninstall python 2.7.10 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I installed python 2.7.10 by following this tutorial:
https://letmespeakweb.wordpress.com/2016/08/15/how-to-install-python-2-7-10-on-ubuntu-16-04/

And now I don't know how to uninstall. I tried purge but it didn't work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://askubuntu.com

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242702/how-to-remove-python-2-from-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the issue quickly, I found an answer to a similar issue. Have you already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48899604/how-to-uninstall-python-in-ubuntu-completely-and-reinstalling-it#50367498)?

Also, based on what I've seen online so far, it might be best to leave it alone. Granted, I don't know *why* you need to uninstall, so please take my suggestions with a grain of salt. I'm certainly no expert with this kind of thing. I'll add to this answer as I find more information. Good luck!